# Google App Engine: Allow Admins to Upload Data via Python Script

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an application hosted on Google App Engine and would like to make uploading data more secure.  Currently, I upload data by using a python script to make POST requests with the relevant data to a URL on the /_ah/spi/... path (and the app takes care of uploading the data correctly). My goal is to make uploading data only available to admins of the application.  I tried specifying an admin security-constraint for /_ah/spi/* in my web.xml but this seemed to block me from being able to upload data.

What is the best/easiest way only allow admins to upload data via my python script?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite get exactly what I wanted (allow access to my application endpoints by admins only) but I did find a way to secure it.  I followed the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth).  Basically I had to:

1. generate a client ID via the google developer console
2. add the client ID to the @Api annotation (under clientIds) for my endpoint
3. add a User parameter to all of the protected methods
4. authenticate myself using OAuth and my public/secret client ID (generated in step 1) in my python script ([sample code here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth))

This scheme at least requires the script accessing my application to have both the public/secret client ID. Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021932/user-authorization-for-cloud-endpoints) had some very useful information.